# Set hard resolution for RDP and how resolution works with RDP

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, resolution

I have written a program that performs some mouseclicks on the screen, this is wonderful and working fine however when I RDP in from another location those mouseclicks change due to the resolution change.  Is there a server setting that forces it to a certain resolution rather than setting these on my local machine?

Also, after I close the RDP does that desktop keep the same resolution as when I had it open last?

Comment: I'm not aware of any option to force the host to keep its resolution because it makes a new session for the client. (You can set it at the client to the desired resolution on connect, though.) But wouldn't it be better to adjust your program to search for the location of the buttons so your program would work with all resolutions? You might even use something like [ControlClick](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/139137-how-to-simulate-mouse-click-without-moving-the-cursor/) like [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) does.